# How to use JQUERY in ASP.NET Core？

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I am a newbie in ASP.NET Core, and I want to use the downloaded jQuery package. I have downloaded a jQuery package now, but how do I introduce it into my view?

I already have the nuget package

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="jQuery" Version="3.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.1.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For client library,when you install the nuget package,it would not shown in your project.It would exist in `%UserProfile%\.nuget\package` by default.

But we usually use LibMan to manage common client-side library files,here is the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-the-add-client-side-library-dialog) of LibMan.
You need to

- choose `filesystem` in Provider
- choose the library location
- choose `Include all library files`
- type target location
  Then you can use

[image]

After click Install,it will generate a `libman.json`.Then you can use the following code to reference js in `wwwwroot/lib`.

```
<script src="~/lib/..."></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, I need to download jquery in wwwroot and the quote is successful!

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you accept it as an answer?Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply:)